# How to remove the last "->" in a word ladder

Tags: java

I am printing out elements from an array list and I want to have "->" in between each word except the last word. My current code is as showed below:

```
for(int m = result.size()-1; m > -1; m--)
{
   System.out.print(result.get(m) + " -> ");
}
```

Actual output from my code:

```
Path of word ladder: abase -> abash ->
```

Expected output:

```
Path of wordladder: abase -> abash
```

Comment: Ask yourself this question: Based on the above code, what condition do you think would have to be true in order for it to be the "last" word?

Comment: Well, why would you *expect* it to only have one arrow? Every time you print anything you print an element of `result` and an arrow...

Comment: If you're using Java 8, use `StringJoiner`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any Java versions:

```
 System.out.print(result.get(m) + (m==0?"":" -> "));
```

Comment: would you mind explaining `m==0?"":"`

Comment: Not a problem :)  It is an inline alternative to if statement. next are equivalents:

Comment: String letter = m==0?"a":"b";

Comment: String letter; If (m==0) { letter="a";} else {letter = "b";}

Comment: So, that construction can be used inline instead of write if else block. Some people do not like it.; Code becomes less readable, but I use it from time to time. I do not like duplicate lines and temp variables when I can aviod them. See one operation vs. 4 and temp variable

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, a simple if condition could handle that one case:

```
if (m==0)
System.out.print(result.get(m));

else
System.out.print(result.get(m) + " -> ");
```

Comment: aren't you forgetting an else ?

Comment: Yes, missed that. thanks for pointing it out.